# How do I build an OpenFire plugin using Gradle in Intellij?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, openfire

According to the OpenFire documentation (https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/plugin-dev-guide.html) to build a custom plugin I need to create a jar with the following folder structure:

```
myplugin/
 |- plugin.xml      <- Plugin definition file
 |- readme.html     <- Optional readme file for plugin, which will be displayed to end users
 |- changelog.html  <- Optional changelog file for plugin, which will be displayed to end users
 |- logo_small.gif  <- Optional small (16x16) icon associated with the plugin (can also be a .png file)
 |- logo_large.gif  <- Optional large (32x32) icon associated with the plugin (can also be a .png file)
 |- classes/        <- Resources your plugin needs (i.e., a properties file)
 |- database/       <- Optional database schema files that your plugin needs
 |- i18n/           <- Optional i18n files to allow for internationalization of plugins.
 |- lib/            <- Libraries (JAR files) your plugin needs
 |- web             <- Resources for Admin Console integration, if any
     |- WEB-INF/
         |- web.xml           <- Generated web.xml containing compiled JSP entries
         |- web-custom.xml    <- Optional user-defined web.xml for custom servlets
     |- images/
```

I know there is an Ant build script to help do this but I couldn't find it and I'm having a hard enough time with Gradle and Maven, I'd rather not add having to learn Ant and deal with XML on to my list of chores. So, I tried to make a Gradle build script. Unfortunately Gradle still doesn't make any sense to me and in Intellij it seems to just do whatever it wants.

Regardless, this is the Gradle script I came up with.

```
task buildPluginJar {
    group 'build'
    description 'Builds OpenFire Plugin Jar'
    println 'Clean old libs and classes.'
    delete 'pluginDefinition/lib/*'
    delete 'pluginDefinition/classes/*'
    println 'Copy libs.'
    copy {
        into 'pluginDefinition/lib'
        from configurations.runtime
    }
    println 'Copy classes.'
    copy {
        into 'pluginDefinition/classes'
        from 'build/classes'
    }
    println 'Build jar.'
    String outputPath = 'build/out/' + project.name + '.jar';

    jar {
        into outputPath
        from fileTree('pluginDefinition/').include('**/*').collect { zipTree it }
    }
}
```

I managed to get the file copying to work, but the end where it's supposed to put it all into a signal jar isn't working. It completes but there is no jar output. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not figure out how to do this with Gradle. But I did figure out how to build jars with Intellij. I followed this tutorial:
http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/08/quickly-create-jar-artifact/

I went through the File > Project Structure menu and added two artifacts. One to build the jar with all of the java code in my pluginDefinition/lib folder, and another to build a jar with the full contents of the pluginDefinition folder that I could install on my Openfire server.

Still, it would have been nice if I could have done this with Gradle.